# Mounting uinput.ko file on DM368 board

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am using DM368 board on linux platform. I have uinput.c file as inbuilt on board, but i dont know  how to generate .ko file out of this. Also how to mount this file on DM368 board. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the steps from [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html) tutorial to compile your kernel module

Create a Makefile

```
obj-m := uinput.o
KDIR := <point to your Linux kernel source directory>
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

Then invoke make

```
make
```